# In Vim, how to search for a WORD boundary?

Tags: regex, vim

### Missing Feature in VIM Regex

I like how Vim distinguishes between [words](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#word) and [WORDs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#WORD), but this distinction seems to be missing from the regexp syntax.  I can use the `\<` and `\>` atoms to searching for a word boundary (with zero width).  But what if I want to search for a WORD boundary?  Seems like there should be an [ordinary atom](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#pattern-atoms) for a WORD, but there isn't.

### Motivating example

Suppose I have the following source code:

```java
public class Example {
    static final String BOOK = "The Republic";
    static final String pub_sub_url = "http://non-public.server.io";
}
```

Out of the 4 occurrences of the substring "pub", I want to match the 2 that begin at a WORD boundary: the regex should match the pub in **pub**lic and **pub**_sub_url but should *not* match the pub in Re**pub**lic or non-**pub**lic.

The `\<` syntax (regex `\<pub`) makes it very easy to exclude Re**pub**lic while matching the other 3. But I want an [atom](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#pattern-atoms) that "Matches the beginning of a WORD."

### Workarounds

I found some ways to do it, but they are unsatisfactorily bulky / clumsy for what should be a common use case.

Here's the best I could come up for as an equivalent of `\<` but for a WORD instead of a word:

```
\(\(\s\)\@<=\|^\)
```

It matches *either* a white-space character with zero-width look-behind, *or* beginning-of-line.  It seems to do what I want, but it's kind of a monster for something I'd like to reuse frequently.

I also have an ever-so-slightly simpler, but also less-general version, which uses `\zs` instead of the zero-width look-behind.  This one only works when it's the start of your match (i.e., you can't use it in the middle of the thing you want to match):

```
\(^\|\s\)\zs
```

Is there a way to define my own atom for this?  Or somehow make it more convenient to use?  Anybody have any other, better idioms they use for this case?

Comment: What you are trying to me means `\S\@<!\S+\S\@!`. If your requirement is something else please elaborate.

Comment: Hi @revo, `\S\@<!\S+\S\@!` doesn't work, but it did give me some new insight: I had been thinking that `\S\@<!` is the same as `\s\@<=`, but it's not.  And it turns out that `\S\@<!` is in fact what I'm looking for, and it matches an answer given below by @djmcmayhem.

Comment: What does `doesn't work` mean? In what way it doesn't work? Please show us some inputs and desired matches from those.

Comment: @revo for example, when matching the text "read-raid": the regex `\<r..d` matches both "read" and "raid".  I'm looking for a regex of the form `⍰r..d` which only matches "read", and does not match "raid".  So the `⍰` that I'm looking for will be the equivalent of `\<` but for WORD instead of word.

My initial proposal of `\(\(\s\)\@<=\|^\)` works, because `\(\(\s\)\@<=\|^\)r..d` matches "read" but not "raid".  `\S\@<!\S+\S\@!` doesn't work, because `\S\@<!\S+\S\@!r..d` doesn't match anything in the sample text.

DJMcMayhem's proposal below works because `\S\@<!r..d` matches "read" only.

Comment: So I think you shouldn't have linked to [WORD](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#WORD) because it differs from your interpretation: `A WORD consists of a sequence of non-blank characters, separated with white
space.  An empty line is also considered to be a WORD.` which means `\S+` with spaces at both ends.

Comment: and still your rules to why `read` should be matched out of `read-raid` is not clear. What's wrong with `raid`?

Comment: @revo sorry, yes, I see the need for a better motivating example. I have edited the question now with a motivating example. As for `read-raid`, what's wrong with `raid` is that it's not at the start of a WORD boundary.

Comment: I filed https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/27782 to request this feature for NeoVim, and https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/14164 for vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first off, depending on what you want, there could be a simpler approach. `\<\>` are dependent on the `iskeyword` setting, so if you want to change those to always operate on WORDS, you can just modify that setting. But if you want to use both, that won't work.

Here's the shortest thing I could come up with:

```
" \< for WORD
\S\@<!

" \> for WORD
\S\@!
```

Explanation:

- `\S\@<!`

  `\S` means "a non-whitespace character", and `\@<!` means "Matches with zero width if the preceding atom does NOT match just before what follows."
- `\S\@!`

  `\S\@!` NOT followed by a non-whitespace character.

Using these lookaheads/lookbehinds is more elegant, because you don't have to special case beginning/end of line.

> Is there a way to define my own atom for this?

Unfortunately, not that I know of. Probably your best bet would be something like:

```
cnoreabbrev <something> \S\@<!
cnoreabbrev <something> \S\@!
```

It's worth noting that these will match empty lines, whereas `\<\>` will not. That's what you trade off for having a shorter regex.

Comment: This is really nice, it's a big improvement over mine, and is in fact short enough that I can see typing it out when I need it.  Thanks!!

Comment: One small nit: `\S\@<!` works perfectly as a WORD-equivalent of `\<`.  However, `.\S\@!` doesn't work as a WORD-equivalent of `\>`.  Instead just drop the starting `.` and use `\S\@!`, which does exactly what I want.

Comment: To see the difference: in a buffer with the text "speed-read" and with hlsearch turned on, try these two searches: searching for `e.d\>` matches both `eed` and `ead`.  Searching for `e.d\S\@!` matches just `ead` as I would expet.  But searching for `e.d.\S\@!` (your variant) doesn't match anything.

Comment: @jbyler Oh duh, I should have noticed that. I'll make a quick edit.

Comment: This matches all spaces between words too, `\S\@<!\<` does the job correctly.

Comment: @adamency good point about `\S\@<!` by itself also matching spaces between words, and your fix does work for that specific case. But I want a combining piece that works as part of a larger regex, and for that case @djmcmayhem's answer works but yours does not. Specifically: `\S\@<!"` matches `"` at the start of a WORD as desired. But `\S\@<!\<"` does not because `"` is not an `iskeyword` character.

Comment: A general solution that works to match a start-of-WORD boundary, either by itself or in combination with a following regex: `\S\@<!\S\@=` but it's getting pretty unwieldy now.

Comment: And the corresponding one for end-of-WORD boundary, either by itself or in combination with a preceding regex: `\s\@<!\S\@!`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another workaround. Just make it easier to set and reset the `iskeyword` option, by adding this to `~/.vimrc`:

```
" make words be whitespace-delimited, like WORD, for use with \< \>
nnoremap <leader>/W :set iskeyword=!-~<CR>
" restore default definition of words
nnoremap <leader>/w :set iskeyword&<CR>
```